# Function call in route file - node.js

Tags: node.js

**Below code is not working because there is function call.**

```
function checkQueryStringExists(request) {
    var url_parts = url.parse(request.url, true);
    var api_token = url_parts.query.api_token;
    if(typeof api_token === 'undefined') {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

router.post("/get-profile", function(request, response) {
    response.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');

    var result = checkQueryStringExists(request);
    if(!result) {
        response.status(401).send(JSON.stringify({ "Status": false, "Message": "Invalid query string." }));
    }
});
```

**Below code works because function call has been removed**

```
router.post("/get-profile", function(request, response) {
    response.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');

    var url_parts = url.parse(request.url, true);
    var api_token = url_parts.query.api_token;
    if(typeof api_token === 'undefined') {
        response.status(401).send(JSON.stringify({ "Status": false, "Message": "Invalid query string." }));
    }

});
```

**Does it means that we can't use functions in node.js like above?**

Comment: Use your function as a middleware

Comment: can't I use the functions like doing in c++ or .net or php?

Comment: Umm well js is way different from strongly typed language such as c++ ,js is single threaded and asynchronous

Answer (score 0):

In node js you may define your functions without specifying the function keyword. You can have two approaches to define your functions:

***APPROACH 1***

```
checkQueryStringExists(request) {
    var url_parts = url.parse(request.url, true);
    var api_token = url_parts.query.api_token;
    if(typeof api_token === 'undefined') {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

***APPROACH 2***

```
checkQueryStringExists = (request) => {
    var url_parts = url.parse(request.url, true);
    var api_token = url_parts.query.api_token;
    if(typeof api_token === 'undefined') {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Avaft

Answer (score 0):

You can definitely use functions in NodeJS. Though the best way to use function would be with async/await so you can ensure that your function actually returns before proceeding with the code.

```
checkQueryStringExists(request) {
    return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
        var url_parts = url.parse(request.url, true);
        var api_token = url_parts.query.api_token;
        if(typeof api_token === 'undefined') {
            resolve(false);
        }
        resolve(true);
    }
});

router.post("/get-profile", async function(request, response) {
    response.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
    try{
        var result = await checkQueryStringExists(request);
        if(!result) {
            response.status(401).send(JSON.stringify({ "Status": false, "Message": "Invalid query string." }));
        } catch (e){
          console.log(e)
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Node.js is asynchronous programming , it is not like c++ , or other language in which the code run one by one , you have to write callback or promise or async/await to run it in synchronous .

The thing i use is callback , you can use same way promise ansd asyn/await. :)
Let me know you want any explanation on this.

```
  function checkQueryStringExists(request, callback) {
        var url_parts = url.parse(request.url, true);
        var api_token = url_parts.query.api_token;
        if(typeof api_token === 'undefined') {
            return callback(false);
        }
        return callback(true);
    }

    router.post("/get-profile", function(request, response) {
        response.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');

        checkQueryStringExists(request,function(status){
                 if(!status) {
                      response.status(401).send(JSON.stringify({ "Status": false, "Message":"Invalid query string." }));
                    }else{
                      response.status(200).send(JSON.stringify({ "Status": true, "Message":"query string is ok." }));
                    }

          });

    });
```